# Transaction isolation level -1 not supporting

Tags: java, sql

I connected the spring application to smartbaer servicev, where the virtual data source (Postgres) created.

Driver class: `"com.smartbear.servicev.jdbc.driver.JdbcVirtDriver"`

Connection String (Local servicev virtual server url): `"jdbc:servicev://localhost:10080"`

> Application.properties :-
>
> spring.datasource.driver-class-name=com.smartbear.servicev.jdbc.driver.JdbcVirtDriver
>
> spring.datasource.url=jdbc:servicev://localhost:10080
>
> spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
>
> spring.jpa.show-sql=true

It is showing the following error while executing SQL from spring boot project (Only for JPA and JDBC Template).

> Failed to obtain JDBC Connection; nested exception is java.sql.SQLException: Exception: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: Transaction isolation level -1 not supported.

But it is working properly for the following basic code.

> `@Bean
>     public DataSource getDataSource() {
>     try {
>         Class.forName("com.smartbear.servicev.jdbc.driver.JdbcVirtDriver");
>         } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
>             e.printStackTrace();
>         } 
>         DriverManagerDataSource driverManager = new 
>              DriverManagerDataSource("jdbc:servicev://localhost:10080", "", "");
>         return driverManager;
>     }`

Comment: Please read [ask] and edit the question and post a [mcve].

Comment: That's clearly a bug in that software you are using. Valid values for the isolation level are 0,1,24 and 8 https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/java.sql/java/sql/Connection.html

Comment: Better link: https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/11/docs/api/constant-values.html#java.sql.Connection.TRANSACTION_NONE

Comment: You need to add a [mre], and include the full stacktrace of your exception. That `JdbcVirtDriver` appears to be using invalid values. Report a bug with them.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same error and tracked it down to trying to connect to a newer version Postresql than the code expected.